# Is there an easy way of setting all other states other than e.target.name to false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Real problem - I want onclick on Link.  Link is not working after that-

```
<li className={this.state.selectedState === "jobs" ? "nav-item active" : "nav-item"}> <Link to = {{type: "JOBLIST", payload : { id : this.props.company_id, status : "active" }}} className="nav-link" name = "jobs" onClick ={this.onclick1}>JOBS</Link> </li>
```

This is my component's constructor function  :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        a: true,
        b: false,
        c: false,
        d: false
    }
}
```

These are for links, if I click on any of them, it triggers onclick1 function.

```
<a href="#" name="a" onClick={this.onclick1} > a </a>
<a href="#" name="b" onClick={this.onclick1} > b </a>
<a href="#" name="c" onClick={this.onclick1} > c </a>
<a href="#" name="d" onClick={this.onclick1} > d </a>
```

so this onclick1 will set the state corresponding to the target as true. ** But I want to set all other states to false except the selected tag. Any easier way of doing other then if else if else if else statements ?**

```
onclick1 = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("name header" + e.target.name)
    let value = true;
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
}
```

Comment: Instead of having mulitple `state` booleans, you could have just one `selectedState` variable (e.g. `this.selectedState = "a";`).

Comment: i want to do something like this after that. 
<a className = {this.state.a ? "x" : "y"} href="#" name="a" onClick={this.onclick1} > a </a>

Comment: You can do this: `<a className = {this.selectedState === "a" ? "x" : "y"} href="#" name="a" onClick={this.onclick1} > a </a>`.

Comment: Thanks man. Awesome.

Comment: Actually this is the real problem now. 
I want onclick on Link.

<li className={this.state.selectedState === "jobs" ? "nav-item active" : "nav-item"}>
                      <Link to = {{type: "JOBLIST", payload : {
                        id : this.props.company_id,
                        status : "active"
                      }}}  className="nav-link"  name = "jobs" onClick ={this.onclick1}>JOBS</Link>
                    </li>

Link is not working after that.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do your homework

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using some initialState variable for this. For example:

```
const initialState = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: false,
};

class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { ...initialState };
  }

  onClick(e) {
    this.setState({
      ...initialState,
      [e.target.name]: true,
    });
  }
}
```

So inside of your click handler you just setting initial state and setting only a single key's value to true

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: '',
    };
    this.links = { 'a': false, 'b': false, 'c': false, 'd': false },      
  }

  onclick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("name header" + e.target.name)
    this.links = {
      ...this.links,
      [`${this.state.selected}`]: false,
    };
    this.setState({
      selected: e.target.name,
    });
  }

  render() {
   return (
     <div>
       {
         Object.keys(this.links).map(key => {
           return <a href="#" name={key} onClick={this.onclick1} >{key} </a>
         });
       }
     </div>
   );
  }

}
```